# Stack Overflow layout optimized for 800x600 resolution

Tags: script, style, userstyle

You got a small monitor? No problem! Install this user style to browse Stack Overflow without having to zoom out.

[<kbd>**DOWNLOAD NOW FOR FREE!**</kbd>](https://userstyles.org/styles/162544/stack-overflow-for-800x600-resolution)   <sub><sup>(From userstyles.org)</sup></sub>

Comment: You know, you can also just click the "Mobile" link at the bottom of any Stock Overflow page.

Comment: @BrockAdams: +1 for "Stock Overflow"